# Using Naive bayes classification on android

Tags: java, android, parsing, classification, naivebayes

I am developing an android news app that should extract specific news topics from the web then make further classification to group news articles in categories using naive Bayes classification, any body know how to implement it in Android or even in Java ?

Comment: Interesting question but seems ill-suited for SO. Perhaps SE Programmers or (apologies SE) Quora would yield a better response. To me, question reads "In search of application solution architect".

Answer (score 1):

You could try finding an [open source Java implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=naive+bayes&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: I tried but I didn't find it in java.

Comment: @Daisy The link I provided is filtered to show Java implementations from GitHub.

Comment: oh ,,, thank you, i'll check it out now .